# Static inner class issue in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have defined the static inner class `Tetromino` but I am getting a compile error in the line:

```
Tetrominoes.add(tetr);
```

and I cannot figure out why.  Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tetris{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    static class Tetromino
    {

        ArrayList<Tetromino> Tetrominoes = new ArrayList<Tetromino>();

        Tetromino tetr = new Tetromino();

        Tetrominoes.add(tetr); //This line generates an error

    }

}
```

In Eclipse, it underlines the line I stated above with red, however when I compile, It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at Tetris.main(Tetris.java:5)
```

where line 5 is my declaration of the main method.

Comment: You can't put method calls directly in the body of a class.

Comment: Never run a program that has compiler error.

Comment: Why shouldn't you ever run a program with a compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement should be added in an non-static initializer, method or constructor:

For example, the case with the constructor will look like this:

```
public Tetromino() {
    Tetrominoes.add(tetr);
}
```